# HTA how to position window to the corner?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I need to position the Window to 0,0

How can I do this using VBScript and HTA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to avoid the the Scripting Guy's chaos (script between head and body) and to show Top Level (out of function) code in .HTA:

```
<html>
 <!-- stolen & sanitized from:
      !! http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/10/how-can-i-center-an-hta-on-the-screen.aspx
 -->
 <head>
  <title>TopLeft HTA</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION
    APPLICATIONNAME="TopLeft HTA"
  >
  <SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    window.moveTo 0, 0
  </SCRIPT>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Extracting the answer from [The Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/10/how-can-i-center-an-hta-on-the-screen.aspx) it would be:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>My Awesome HTA</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="objHTA"
     APPLICATIONNAME="Awesome HTA"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>
</head>

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    Sub Window_Onload
        window.moveTo 0, 0
    End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<!--/*    the rest of you HTA goes here...   */-->
```